# Sequelize delete multiple associations

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Hi I have the following tables

```
models.User= sequelize.define("User", {
   name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true
    }
});
models.Group= sequelize.define("Group", {
   name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true
    }
});


db.User.belongsToMany(db.Group, {
  "through": "UsersGroup"
});

db.Group.belongsToMany(db.User, { 
  "through": "UsersGroup"
});
```

Is there a way to delete at once many user from a group, given the group name ,  and the names (users) to delete?

**like:**

```
var groupName = 'Work';

var users = ['Alice','Bob']
```

So I need to delete the association between Work group and {Alice and Bob}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `"through": "UsersGroup"` will automatically create a new Model UsersGroup however it won't associate it with User and Group directly. So what i'd do is to create a new sequelize model UsersGroup with whatever attributes and keys and define the association to User and Group. Then instead of passing "UsersGroup" string to `belongsToMany` you use the model directly as db.UsersGroup.

```
models.UsersGroup = sequelize.define("UsersGroup", {});

db.UsersGroup.belongsTo(db.User);
db.UsersGroup.belongsTo(db.Group);
db.UsersGroup.findAll({attributes:['id'], include:[
  {model: db.User, where: {name: {$in:['Alice','Bob']}}},
  {mode: db.Group, where: {name: 'Work'}}
]}).then(function(toBeDeleted){
  return db.UsersGroups.destroy({where:{id:{$in:toBeDeleted.map(function(d){ return d.id})}}})
}).then(function(){
  ....
}).catch(function(dbErr){throw err;})
```

You also might want to check `if toBeDeleted.length > 0` as i remember sequelize was acting funny when an empty array is passed.

Also in case you don't have id as primary key in usersgroup table you can easily modify the code above to use combination of user_id and group_id - Just modify the where statements.

The other approach could be selecting Users and Groups separately and use resulting sets in `UsersGroups.destroy()`. But i prefer to have an association even from a through model.

If you were to delete associations just based on group name OR user name you'd be able to do that using `removeAssociation` or `removeAssociations` have a looj [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/associations/belongs-to-many/)

Comment: Hi, Thanks it looks like a very good and elegant solution, but im getting the following error User is not associated to UserGroups! although it is .

Comment: Sorry, my fault, if not explicitly defined the automatically created through model has no association to its referenced models. I edited the answer - You'll have to define UsersGroup model, specify associations to User and Group and use the model reference in through instead on just string. The other solution would be just filtering Users and Group separately and then use resulting ids to delete from UsersGroup

Comment: Thanks!, So if I have Users ids, and group Id do I still have to define models.UsersGroup = sequelize.define("UsersGroup", {}); in order to preform the deletion ? or I can do some query on the referenced model (UsersGroup)?

Comment: Nope you don't have to define it then ... you just need to get users and group first as you said

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing that(role-> group , action->user)

```
  var role = JSON.parse(req.body.role);
  var actions = JSON.parse(req.body.actions);
  var actionNames = _.map(actions, function (action) { return action.name });
  models.Role.findOne({ where: { name: role.name } }).then(function (_role) {
    if (_role == null) {
      res.status(500).send("role was not found");
    }
    else {
      models.Action.findAll({ where: { name: actionNames } }).then(function (actionsToRemove) {
        if (actionsToRemove == null) {
          res.status(500).send("No action [" + action.name + "] was found");
        }
        else {
          _role.removeActions(actionsToRemove).then(function (removedActions) {
            if (removedActions == null || removedActions != actions.length) {
              res.status(500).send(actions.length + " Action expected to be removed , but only [" + removedActions + "] were removed");
            }
            else {
              res.send("" + removedActions);
            }
          }).catch(function (err) {
            throw err;
          })
        }
      })
    }
  }).catch(function (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  });
```